# Geting error when printing the return value of a function in python

Tags: python, spyder

Am declaring a function in python, but when am printing it it is throwing an error. I am new to python, am using python 3.5.2, below is my code, please guide me.

```
def myfunc(x):
    y=x*2
    x=27
    return y

print myfunc(5)
```

Error message is:
 print myfunc(5)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks & regards,
Sanjay.

Comment: print(myfunc(5))

Comment: in python3 there is different syntax for `print` replace your last line to `print(myfunc(5))`

Comment: Thank youi rain_ its working for me.